# reach images in js file in visual studio

Tags: jquery

Hi i'm trying out a new jquery plugin: https://github.com/rewish/jquery-bgswitcher
My problem is when i try to link the images i get 404 not found for all my images.

```
      $("body").bgswitcher({
    images:
        [
            "/Content/Images/landscape_argentina_mountain_lake_patagonia_clouds_nature.jpg",
            "/Content/Images/2510_venezuela.jpg",
            "/Content/Images/8.jpg",
            "/Content/Images/IguazuFallsNationalParkathebordersofArgentinaandBrazil20130211.jpg",
            "/Content/Images/Rio-Movie-Wallpaper-6.jpg",
            "/Content/Images/snowy_mountains_patagonia_peaks_chile_farm_ultra_3840x2160_hd-wallpaper-1906502.jpg",
            "/Content/Images/Sunset_And_Lightning_Over_River_FullHDWpp.com_.jpg"
        ],
    loop: true,
    interval: 5000,
    effect: "face"
});
```

How do i link my images from visual studio from my map /Content/Images

Comment: please show us the structure of your solution , could you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this method :

```
function getFull(a)
{//get full url including scheme , port and base dns
 return  location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+(location.port ? ':'+location.port: '') + a;
}
```

And then :

```
$("body").bgswitcher({
images:
    [
        getFull("/Content/Images/landscape_argentina_mountain_lake_patagonia_clouds_nature.jpg"),
        getFull("/Content/Images/2510_venezuela.jpg"),
        getFull("/Content/Images/8.jpg"),
        getFull("/Content/Images/IguazuFallsNationalParkathebordersofArgentinaandBrazil20130211.jpg"),
        getFull("/Content/Images/Rio-Movie-Wallpaper-6.jpg"),
        getFull("/Content/Images/snowy_mountains_patagonia_peaks_chile_farm_ultra_3840x2160_hd-wallpaper-1906502.jpg"),
        getFull("/Content/Images/Sunset_And_Lightning_Over_River_FullHDWpp.com_.jpg")
    ],
loop: true,
interval: 5000,
effect: "face"
```

});

So ( for example) :

```
getFull("/Content/Images/landscape_argentina_mountain_lake_patagonia_clouds_nature.jpg")
```

Will yield :

```
https://lostechies.com/Content/Images/landscape_argentina_mountain_lake_patagonia_clouds_nature.jpg"
```

*(^ I run the sample on a console on random site so ignore the base url. In your site - it will be fine.)*

**Performance Edit:**

Instead of calculating each time the whole url , let's memoize it :

```
 function getFull(a)
    { 
     return  getFull.mem || (getFull.mem = location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+(location.port ? ':'+location.port: '') + a,getFull.mem)
    }
```